# Playstore error 491

Tags: android

I writen 2 application and upload to playstore. with nhomxe aplication, i use mobile download normal. But with softflows business, when i download it notify error 491, can't download and setup.I repeat proccess download, run normal. I don't know this error have reason from my application or from google service.
My link application

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=longvan.mobile.SoftFlows_Business_Mobile
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=longvan.mobile.nhomxe
```

Comment: Do you use a custom rom? It happens with almost every app to me, and the only thing I can think about is that my custom rom is still a little buggy (with the stock rom it never happened)

Comment: i retry on rom stock and rom cook, result is same.

Answer (score 0):

Try these two methods to fix [error 491](http://appslova.com/android-fix-error-491-google-play-store/):

**Method 1**: Delete and re-add your Google account

Go to system settings>> Accounts>>Google>>Remove your Gmail account (the account that is synched with Google Play Store)
Now from settings>>Apps>>All> Force stop, Clear data and cache for Google Play Store, Google Service Framework and Download Manager
Reboot your device.
Now again go to settings>> Accounts>>Google>>Add your Gmail account
Rerun Google Play Store and update or install your app.

**Method 2**: Wipe Cache

This method requires that you can go into a recovery mode like Clockworkmod Recovery.

Reboot into recovery
Wipe cache partition
Go to Advanced >> Wipe Dalvik Cache
Now go back and Reboot system
Rerun Google Play Store and update or install your app.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your date and time is set correctly. After pondering for hours, found out that that is the issue.